# How to put public download url link in APILayer Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How to make `A publicly reachable URL to download the resume (pdf/docx/doc formats supported)` in c# asp.net.
I am using api of `APILayer` ,, and api example code blow. My pdf files are saved in local folders in app.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.apilayer.com/resume_parser/url?url={url}");
client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("apikey", "KEY");

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

How to put `{url}` which saved in my project folder?

How to put {url} which saved in my project folder?

Comment: A local folder isn't a `publicly reachable URL`. Put them on a server that can give you such a url.

Comment: But i want to use locally, as i am student , i dont want to publish

Comment: your case if very confusing and a weird use case. Also the question 'How to put {url} which saved in my project folder?' doesn't say much about your process or flow. Can you provide more info/code/flow/ etc?

Comment: Hi,, in simple word please just let me know how can i use this API on my local host, i am using asp.net c# web forms. My pdf file contains in folder... Thats it,

Comment: @NielsLucas i am using this very simple api for resume parser, [link](https://apilayer.com/marketplace/resume_parser-api)

Comment: Hi @ZahidLateef. Could you please provide us some test cases, expected result? This will help us to provide you with the most appropriate solution to the problem.